# Issue with .bashrc on starting gcloud beta interactive

Tags: bash, gcloud

When I run `gcloud beta interactive`, the start up message produces this error:

```
Welcome to the gcloud interactive shell environment.

    Tips:

      ▪ start by typing commands to get auto-suggestions and inline help
      ▪ use tab, up-arrow, or down-arrow to navigate completion dropdowns
      ▪ use space or / to accept the highlighted dropdown item
      ▪ run gcloud <alpha|beta> interactive --help for more info

    Run $ gcloud feedback to report bugs or request new features.

/home/dylanrussell/.bashrc: line 4: $'\r': command not found
/home/dylanrussell/.bashrc: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'home/dylanrussell/.bashrc: line 6: `case $- in
```

The relevant part of my `.bashrc` is:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this error message. It seems `gcloud` continues to work for me regardless but I would still like to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you have conflict due to linux/windows new line characters?
Please use any tool (there are hundreds of them) that shows you hex-code of your bashrc to see what you have at the end of line.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what this is. My Visual Studio Code (which I must have used at some point to open this file) was set to CRLF line endings. Easy fix, thanks!